# Computed Twig on Date/ Time with Conditions results in php error

Tags: webforms

I was referred here from the [Webform Issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3405568)

**Problem/Motivation**
Calculating the time difference using the Date/ Time elements with any conditions applied to the Computed Twig element results in the php error "TypeError: strtotime(): Argument #1 ($datetime) must be of type string, array given in strtotime()"

**Steps to reproduce**
Add 2 Date/ Time elements, in my case "Start Date and Time" and "End Date and Time".
Add a Computed Twig element (Computed Time Worked).
Code in "Computed value/markup":

```
{# calculate the difference (in days) between two date elements #}
{% set startDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set endDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:end_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set difference = endDate|date('U') - startDate|date('U') %}
{% set differenceDays = (difference / 60 / 60 )%}
{{ differenceDays }}
```

Set Visible or Enabled condition to any value.

Save elements and fill out the webform. The browser returns:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal logs the following:

> TypeError: strtotime(): Argument #1 ($datetime) must be of type string, array given in strtotime() (line 188 of (redacted)/web/modules/contrib/webform/src/Plugin/WebformElement/DateBase.php)

Removing the condition from the Computed Twig element allows it to function properly and the computed time range is returned.

Stack Trace:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: strtotime(): Argument #1 ($datetime) must be of type string, array given in strtotime() (line 188 of modules/contrib/webform/src/Plugin/WebformElement/DateBase.php).
strtotime() (Line: 188)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\DateBase->formatTextItem() (Line: 1373)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->format() (Line: 1330)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->formatText() (Line: 234)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementManager->invokeMethod() (Line: 1073)
_webform_token_get_submission_value() (Line: 743)
webform_tokens()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 426)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->Drupal\Core\Extension\{closure}() (Line: 405)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith() (Line: 425)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() (Line: 359)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->generate() (Line: 241)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->doReplace() (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->replace() (Line: 152)
Drupal\webform\WebformTokenManager->replace() (Line: 139)
Drupal\webform\Twig\WebformTwigExtension->webformToken() (Line: 39)
__TwigTemplate_5e4d013240f1729da6cb068356187529->doDisplay() (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling() (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 45)
Twig\TemplateWrapper->render() (Line: 234)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->renderInline() (Line: 53)
Drupal\Core\Render\Element\InlineTemplate::preRenderInlineTemplate()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback() (Line: 788)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback() (Line: 374)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 204)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 160)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 159)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain() (Line: 261)
Drupal\webform\Twig\WebformTwigExtension::renderTwigTemplate() (Line: 61)
Drupal\webform\Element\WebformComputedTwig::computeValue() (Line: 320)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\WebformComputedBase->computeValue() (Line: 459)
Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission->getData() (Line: 408)
Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission->getElementData() (Line: 1731)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getValue() (Line: 1760)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getRawValue() (Line: 2267)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getElementSelectorInputValue() (Line: 855)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\OptionsBase->getElementSelectorInputValue() (Line: 765)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->checkCondition() (Line: 735)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->validateCondition() (Line: 658)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->validateConditions() (Line: 642)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->validateConditions() (Line: 536)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->isElementVisible() (Line: 509)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator::elementValidate()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 282)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm() (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm() (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm() (Line: 118)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->validateForm() (Line: 593)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm() (Line: 325)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder->getForm() (Line: 1257)
Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform->getSubmissionForm() (Line: 77)
Drupal\webform\Controller\WebformEntityController->addForm()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 121)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
```

More info:

```
strtotime(Array) (Line: 188)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\DateBase->formatTextItem(Array, Object, Array) (Line: 1373)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->format('Text', Array, Object, Array) (Line: 1330)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->formatText(Array, Object, Array) (Line: 234)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementManager->invokeMethod('formatText', Array, Object, Array) (Line: 1073)
_webform_token_get_submission_value('start_date_and_time:raw', Array, Object, Object, Object) (Line: 743)
webform_tokens('webform_submission', Array, Array, Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 426)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->Drupal\Core\Extension\{closure}(Object, 'webform') (Line: 405)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAllWith('tokens', Object) (Line: 433)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('tokens', Array) (Line: 359)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->generate('webform_submission', Array, Array, Array, Object) (Line: 241)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->doReplace(1, '{webform-token-suffixes:clear}[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw]{/webform-token-suffixes}', Array, Array, Object) (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->replace('{webform-token-suffixes:clear}[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw]{/webform-token-suffixes}', Array, Array, NULL) (Line: 152)
Drupal\webform\WebformTokenManager->replace('{webform-token-suffixes:clear}[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw]{/webform-token-suffixes}', Object, Array, Array) (Line: 139)
Drupal\webform\Twig\WebformTwigExtension->webformToken('[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw:clear]', Object) (Line: 39)
__TwigTemplate_7329624ba7a175f0d60701c986644882->doDisplay(Array, Array) (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render(Array, Array) (Line: 45)
Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array) (Line: 234)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->renderInline('{# inline_template_start #}{# calculate the difference (in days) between two date elements #}
{% set startDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set endDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:end_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set difference = endDate|date('U') - startDate|date('U') %}
{% set differenceDays = (difference / 60 / 60 )%}
{{ differenceDays }}', Array) (Line: 53)
Drupal\Core\Render\Element\InlineTemplate::preRenderInlineTemplate(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 788)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 374)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 204)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 160)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 161)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array) (Line: 261)
Drupal\webform\Twig\WebformTwigExtension::renderTwigTemplate(Object, '{# calculate the difference (in days) between two date elements #}
{% set startDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set endDate = webform_token('[webform_submission:values:end_date_and_time:raw:clear]', webform_submission) ?: 0 |date('d.m.Y H:i:s') %}
{% set difference = endDate|date('U') - startDate|date('U') %}
{% set differenceDays = (difference / 60 / 60 )%}
{{ differenceDays }}', Array) (Line: 61)
Drupal\webform\Element\WebformComputedTwig::computeValue(Array, Object) (Line: 320)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\WebformComputedBase->computeValue(Array, Object) (Line: 459)
Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission->getData() (Line: 408)
Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission->getElementData('submission_type') (Line: 1731)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getValue(Array, Object, Array) (Line: 1760)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getRawValue(Array, Object) (Line: 2267)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase->getElementSelectorInputValue('.webform-submission-call-submissions-add-form :input[name="submission_type"]', 'value', Array, Object) (Line: 855)
Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElement\OptionsBase->getElementSelectorInputValue('.webform-submission-call-submissions-add-form :input[name="submission_type"]', 'value', Array, Object) (Line: 765)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->checkCondition(Array, '.webform-submission-call-submissions-add-form :input[name="submission_type"]', Array, Object) (Line: 735)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->validateCondition('.webform-submission-call-submissions-add-form :input[name="submission_type"]', Array, Object) (Line: 658)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->validateConditions(Array, Object) (Line: 536)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator->isElementVisible(Array, Object) (Line: 509)
Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionConditionsValidator::elementValidate(Array, Object, Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 282)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object) (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object) (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm(Array, Object, 'webform_submission_call_submissions_add_form') (Line: 118)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->validateForm('webform_submission_call_submissions_add_form', Array, Object) (Line: 593)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('webform_submission_call_submissions_add_form', Array, Object) (Line: 325)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder->getForm(Object, 'add') (Line: 1257)
Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform->getSubmissionForm() (Line: 77)
Drupal\webform\Controller\WebformEntityController->addForm(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 718)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Stepping through the debugger the first error that comes up:
[image: First Error]

Here's the second error and the array contents:
[image: Array Contents]

Comment: `webform_token` can return an array, which is probably what is causing this problem when passing the result to `|date`.

Comment: So how do I work around that? Why is it only happening when the computed twig element has a condition applied? Shouldn't the fact that it returns an array already be taken into account since it works without the condition?

Comment: Ok then, get a stack trace.

Comment: Added into the original post

Comment: What is inside the array that is passed to strtotime on line 188?

Comment: Any advice on how to find that?

Comment: Debugging PHP? Use a debugger like xdebug, or, for quick debugs: `var_dump($the_value);exit();`.

Comment: Updated with more information. Is that closer to teasing out the information in the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's an array. You can't pass an array to `|date`. You could probably pass `startDate['date']` to `|date`.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that from the form builder gui?